# Is it a good idea to add meta data in a docker-compose file

Tags: docker-compose

I plan to add meta information in my docker-compose files, but I don't know if it's possible/a good way.

Figure this service, and the meta key:

```
OldMongoDB:
  image: mongo:3.2
  environment:
    - URL: mongodb://localhost:27015
  ports:
    - "27015:27017"
  meta:
    - meta1: "some value usefull in tests"
    - meta2: "other value usefull in tests"
```

Is it good for you to store additional values inside a docker-compose? 
This is to be used by test scripts.

Comment: For this, it is better to use [link](https://pastebin.com/BpVCYRHv)

Comment: The values are not intented for containers.